# How do a OneToMany Unidirectional relationship with mandatory joincolumn?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

How do this relationship be required when the ***em.persist (cliente)*** is executed?

I do not want to map bidirectional.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id",referencedColumnName="ID",insertable=true, nullable=false, columnDefinition="bigint DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL")
public List<Telefone> getTelefones() {
    return telefones;
}
```

Comment: Please give more details: what entities do you have, which one are you trying to `persist`, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to persist the entity where the code snippet was noted. And when I persist an entity without that relationship. I want an exception occurs. For the relationship should be mandatory.